# Google Maps javaScript API Caching

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3

we use API Google Maps, but we're exceeding the quota. Basically we create script side client where set attribute "src" with api value.

Ex:

script.src = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#########&callback=initialize

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

There are way where we can cache the request or at same onload the maps,  where I don't trespass  the terms of google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to cache the Maps JavaScript API across multiple users. Each user needs to load a copy of the library when they're displaying maps.

If you're constantly creating new maps on the *same page* then you can optimize your site by re-using maps.  Each time you create a `new google.maps.Map` you use your quota, if you are showing multiple maps on the same page consider combining them into one big map or re-using existing map elements, changing the options for an existing `map` instead of creating a new one.